# how to read and write file on mac system using java?

Tags: webdriver, java, appium

hi everyone i am new to **mac system**, on window system we read and write data from **excel** sheet what about **mac?** if **notes** is an answer provide me a **java code to read and write data from notes** file.**strong text**

Comment: What you have tried so far?

Comment: iam on search...haven't tried yet....

Comment: If you are using java and selenium webdriver then code to read/write excel would be same which you write with window OS. Mac will allow you to run same code. You might configure all things in Mac properly.

Comment: Since excel works on MAC as well, you should have no issues in reading and writing data in excel files. If you have things in place (mentioned in above), you should be good.

Comment: This feels more appropriate for StackOverflow. However, you can still use Excel as your viewer. I don't know whether you will have the same access to the Excel object model and VBA scripting layer, since that's all based in COM on Windows. However, Excel will load Xml and CSV file formats, so try writing out data like that, and then it's both easy to code against, and editable in excel.

Comment: No problem. Hope your things working.:)

Comment: I'd say this is better for Stack Overflow, but if it were, I'd just migrate it. This question is basically asking someone to write code for you. I'll do you a favor and just point you to [POI](https://poi.apache.org/) which is a Java library for creating Excel files. But the question as it stands is a bad one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

File format doesn't change no matter Windows it or Mac. I believe you need to look into [Apache POI](http://poi.apache.org/) library documentation.

You can refer [How to Extract Data From Files With JMeter](https://blazemeter.com/blog/what-every-performance-tester-should-know-about-extracting-data-files-jmeter) guide for code snippets and useful links.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use JExcel API: http://sourceforge.net/projects/jexcelapi/files/ . And here is an example how to use it: https://github.com/amazpyel/sqa_training/tree/master/Classwork